# How to use uploaded images from an image gallery in an article?

Tags: nodes, media

Maybe I am not searching for the correct terms, but I am trying to use an **image gallery** and be able to **reference** the **images** in that gallery from an **article**.  I want to be able to upload the images **one time**, but then have specific images to be shown in the **article**, either as a **"sub-gallery"** or just **inline** with the text, depending on the context of the article.

Is it just as simple as creating an image tag and setting the source to the relative address inside the drupal site?  Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The module [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) can do the job.

> Entity reference provides a field type that can reference arbitrary
>   entities

...ie your gallery files!

With this module you can add an **"Entity Reference Field"** related to your gallery files to the **Article** Content Type.

Then, for each **Article**, you can add 1 or more images among those already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have had to delay the development of my site due to a project, but I will look into this to get it to work.  This sounds like it will do what I am asking for based on the information you provided.  I will hopefully be able to get back to this during this weekend and report my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Creating galleries is a common request, which can be solved in various ways. [Talking Drupal #083](http://www.talkingdrupal.com/083) is a great podcast about creating a Gallery, and includes a lot of recommended modules for it. Just to mention a few of them (mentioned on the linked page):

> - Gallery formatter - https://www.drupal.org/project/galleryformatter
> - Views Slideshow - https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow
> - Flexslider - https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider
> - Node Gallery - https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery
> - Multiupload  Filefield Widget - https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget
> - Multiupload Imagefield Widget - https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget
> - Field Focus - www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_focus
> - pl upload - https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload

So if you're looking for a better way, consider the above list of modules as a possible shortlist to further explore. Which one is going to be "best" (cfr. the "*better way to accomplish this*" in your question) is a matter of preferences, actual requirements, etc.

Comment: Sounds like I have a bit of work to get to my final solution!  Thanks for the information and I will check out the podcast for further information as well.